# Jquery hover without ID

Tags: jquery, html, css, mousehover

When I move my mouse over one flag, all the other flags switch to hover. But what I want is only the current element switches to hover.

```
<div class="lang-list">
  <a href=" index.php" class="nodisplayflag" class="linkhover">
    <img class="hover1" src="flag1.png">
    <img class="hover2" src="flag1_hover.png" style="display:none">
  </a>

  <a href="index2.php" class="linkhover">
    <img class="hover1" src="flag2.png">
    <img class="hover2" src="flag2_hover.png" style="display:none">
  </a>

  <a href="index3.php" class="linkhover">
    <img class="hover1" src="flag3.png">
    <img class="hover2" src="flag3_hover.png"style="display:none">
  </a>
</div>
```

My Js function here under

```
$(".linkhover").hover(
  function(){
    $(".hover1").hide();
    $(".hover2").show();
  },    

  function(){
    $(".hover1").show();
    $(".hover2").hide();
  }
);
```

Is it a smart way to hover only the current element without using dedicated ID ?

Comment: I think you need **$(this)**... $(this).find('.hover1').hide();

Comment: You can use `this` to select the element that fired the event or `event.target` to select the element targeted by the event. Read more https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/

Comment: You could accomplish this with pure css: https://jsfiddle.net/zgs2xu84/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` to limit the selector to only those found within the current `.linkhover` element (not tested).

```
$(".linkhover").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".hover1").hide();
        $(this).find(".hover2").show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".hover1").show();
        $(this).find(".hover2").hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are selecting all the `.hover1` and `.hover2`.

Try this change:

```
$(".linkhover").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".hover1").hide();
        $(this).find(".hover2").show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".hover1").show();
        $(this).find(".hover2").hide();
    }
);
```

This way you show/hide the elements inside the `.linkhover` being hovered.